# How do I focus whole text on first click and deselected (to normal mode) with the second click?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, methods

Simply on a Textbox.

I already have this Event Method, which works for the focus all:

```
private void DoFocusEverything(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }
```

How can I modify this, to unselect on the second, third, fourth... click?

Comment: `if(textBox.SelectionLength == textBox.Text.Length)` ?

Comment: if that works, I will eat bricks, let me test

Comment: nope doesn't work @Sinatr it won't trigger the first SelectAll because the selection length is already at 0 :D

Comment: Do you want to use the same event?

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes, please. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, i do. Probably, you added above subroutine to MouseClick event. So, every time when you click on textbox, new selection is made. You'll need extra variable to hold old status of selection in the textbox. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code is for a simple textbox on a form.

It uses the `clicksBeforeNormal` variable to count the number of times the mouse down event was fired.
The `textBox1_MouseDown` this is the equivalent of your `DoFocusEverything` event.

```
int clicksBeforeNormal = 0;
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (clicksBeforeNormal < 1)
        textBox.SelectAll();

    //ignore the click count on empty text box
    if (textBox.Text.Length > 0)
        clicksBeforeNormal++;
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clicksBeforeNormal = 0;
}

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    clicksBeforeNormal = 0;
}
```

The `clicksBeforeNormal` gets reset when clicking outside the text box on the form `Form1_MouseDown`, or when the text box is not the active control on the form `textBox1_Leave`.

On the first click, if the textbox is empty the count does not get taken into account.
If the textbox has some text all the text will be selected on the first click. Any subsequent clicks will then return the text box to normal.

[image: selectonclick]

Comment: Thanks, this works fine! Thought you have to work with a big code, but its just simple events. Thx!